# Terraform - foreach list of maps within a list of maps

Tags: for-loop, terraform, devops, terraform-template-file, libreswan

I am currently struggling to wrap my head around how to foreach a list of maps within a list of maps.

```
locals {

  vpn_configurations = [

    {
      customer_name      = "test125231"
      custom_path        = "test123123"
      shared_by          = []
      nat                = false
      nat_source_ip      = ""
      nat_destination_ip = ""
      nat_route          = ""
      tunnels = [
        {
          tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel"
          left          = "%defaultroute"
          leftid        = ""
          leftsubnet    = ""
          leftsourceip  = ""
          rightid       = ""
          right         = ""
          rightsubnet   = ""
          rightsourceip = ""
          ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          keyexchange   = "ike"
          ikev2         = "no"
          esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          salifetime    = 3600
          ikelifetime   = 3600
          authby        = "secret"
          # use auto=start when done testing the tunnel
          auto = "ondemand"
        },
        {
          tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel2"
          left          = "%defaultroute"
          leftid        = ""
          leftsubnet    = ""
          leftsourceip  = ""
          rightid       = ""
          right         = ""
          rightsubnet   = ""
          rightsourceip = ""
          ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          keyexchange   = "ike"
          ikev2         = "no"
          esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          salifetime    = 3600
          ikelifetime   = 3600
          authby        = "secret"
          # use auto=start when done testing the tunnel
          auto = "ondemand"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      customer_name      = "sdfsdfsd"
      custom_path        = "sdfsdfsdf"
      shared_by          = []
      nat                = false
      nat_source_ip      = ""
      nat_destination_ip = ""
      nat_route          = ""
      tunnels = [
        {
          tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel3"
          left          = "%defaultroute"
          leftid        = ""
          leftsubnet    = ""
          leftsourceip  = ""
          rightid       = ""
          right         = ""
          rightsubnet   = ""
          rightsourceip = ""
          ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          keyexchange   = "ike"
          ikev2         = "no"
          esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          salifetime    = 3600
          ikelifetime   = 3600
          authby        = "secret"
          # use auto=start when done testing the tunnel
          auto = "ondemand"
        },
        {
          tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel4"
          left          = "%defaultroute"
          leftid        = ""
          leftsubnet    = ""
          leftsourceip  = ""
          rightid       = ""
          right         = ""
          rightsubnet   = ""
          rightsourceip = ""
          ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          keyexchange   = "ike"
          ikev2         = "no"
          esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
          salifetime    = 3600
          ikelifetime   = 3600
          authby        = "secret"
          # use auto=start when done testing the tunnel
          auto = "ondemand"
        }
      ]
    }

  ]

}
```

I am trying to pass each of the tunnels for each vpn configuration into a terraform template generator in order to create individual configuration files for each tunnel associated with a customer.

```
data "template_file" "networking_configs" {
  for_each = local.vpn_configurations
  template = file("${path.module}/template-files/networking-templates/tunnel-configuration.tpl")
  vars = {

    tunnel_name   = each.value.tunnels["tunnel_name"]
    left          = each.value.tunnels["left"]
    leftid        = module.ipsec.public_ip
    leftsubnet    = each.value.tunnels["leftsubnet"]
    leftsourceip  = data.aws_network_interface.eni_ip.private_ip
    rightid       = each.value.tunnels["rightid"]
    right         = each.value.tunnels["right"]
    rightsubnet   = each.value.tunnels["rightsubnet"]
    rightsourceip = each.value.tunnels["rightsourceip"]
    ike           = each.value.tunnels["ike"]
    keyexchange   = each.value.tunnels["keyexchange"]
    ikev2         = each.value.tunnels["ikev2"]
    esp           = each.value.tunnels["esp"]
    salifetime    = each.value.tunnels["salifetime"]
    ikelifetime   = each.value.tunnels["ikelifetime"]
    authby        = each.value.tunnels["authby"]
    auto          = each.value.tunnels["auto"]

  }
}
```

Appreciate any help available.

Comment: Do you want each tunnel within a nested `object`, or each tunnel across every outer `object`?

Comment: each tunnel across every nested object. So for customer test125231 there would be 2 tunnels created. The amount of tunnels per customer is subject to change and thus I am looking for a way to loop through each customers  "tunnels" and create the tunnel configuration files

Comment: You are looking for this design pattern/algorithm: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flatten your double for loop into one. For example (only some variables listed):

```
locals {
  flat_vpn_configurations = merge([
         for vpn_config in local.vpn_configurations :
         {
             for tunnel in vpn_config["tunnels"]:
             "${vpn_config["customer_name"]}-${tunnel["tunnel_name"]}" =>
              {
                  customer_name = vpn_config["customer_name"]
                  custom_path = vpn_config["custom_path"]
                  tunnel_name = tunnel["tunnel_name"]
                  left = tunnel["left"]
              }
         }
      ]...)
}
```

which will give you `local.flat_vpn_configurations` as (only part shown):

```
{
  "sdfsdfsd-test-tunnel3" = {
    "custom_path" = "sdfsdfsdf"
    "customer_name" = "sdfsdfsd"
    "left" = "%defaultroute"
    "tunnel_name" = "test-tunnel3"
  }
  "sdfsdfsd-test-tunnel4" = {
    "custom_path" = "sdfsdfsdf"
    "customer_name" = "sdfsdfsd"
    "left" = "%defaultroute"
    "tunnel_name" = "test-tunnel4"
  }
  "test125231-test-tunnel" = {
    "custom_path" = "test123123"
    "customer_name" = "test125231"
    "left" = "%defaultroute"
    "tunnel_name" = "test-tunnel"
  }
  "test125231-test-tunnel2" = {
    "custom_path" = "test123123"
    "customer_name" = "test125231"
    "left" = "%defaultroute"
    "tunnel_name" = "test-tunnel2"
  }
}
```

Then you can very easly iterate over `flat_vpn_configurations` with `for_each`.